# I am a student and want to get a Schengen visa

Tags: schengen-visas

I am an international student in the UK. When I applied for my UK visa (to study there), the university was my sponsor. This visa is still valid.

Now I want to apply for a Schengen visa before going back to my home country. Can I currently apply for a Schengen visa without any sponsorship letter from my university?

Comment: please if anyone know about it ,give me some advise

Comment: @rijon islam What is your citizenship? What type of Schengen Visa do you hope to apply for? It’s possible you won’t qualify to apply for a Schengen Visitor visa from the UK unless you can prove your UK visa is valid for at least 90 days after your proposed trip ends, which seems unlikely based on your question.

Comment: @rijonislam I edited your question to make it easier to understand, as parts of it were not clear. If my interpretation of your question is incorrect, please change the corresponding part of the (edited) question.

Answer (score 2):

You usually do not need an invitation letter but you do need strong ties with your home country, which can be your birth country or where you study. 
Without strong ties you will have a hard time to proof you will leave the Schengen area and that may be the reason you will not get a visa.

If you give us your nationality and home country we might be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: I would also note that Schengen visa applicants must justify the purpose of their visit to the Schengen area. One way of doing this is a letter from a "sponsor" (though I don't think that term is used as such), meaning a person or institution that is the reason for the visit.  But it is also possible to visit for personal reasons, such as tourism, without having a sponsor.  Justification of a tourist visit can probably take the form of reservations for accommodation and perhaps other tourist activities.

Comment: @phoog, visiting as tourists is usually accepted as a reason and does not need a sponsor.

Comment: Indeed, I hit "enter" by mistake before I was done with the comment :-)  I want to suggest that since the question is essentially "can I apply without a sponsor letter" perhaps the answer should mention the reasons why such a letter might be useful and the situations in which one might not be necessary.  The question of ties to the home country or in this case country of residence is important, but justification of the purpose of the visit should not be overlooked.